# Creating some type of buffer or merger for CUPS print jobs

Tags: cups

TL;DR: Need to optimize CUPS jobs. The old and optimized version I've been using prints 30 labels in 10 seconds, the newer unoptimized prints 1 in 16 seconds. I suppose they achieved this speed by merging the files and sending all them as only one file for the queue, but don't know exactly how.

I don't really have any experience besides setting up CUPS and less yet with CUPS API, but now I have to create some sort of buffer that takes any number of files and then send to the printer instead of creating print jobs for each file. I've searched a lot, the whole day and yet didn't find anything that could solve this problem.

It's possible to use cupsCreateDestJob from the CUPS API to do that? Or I can use some shell command? Merge the files?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the labels generated a "page at a time" or as single labels? Also is the page size just one label or is it maybe 20 labels on an A4 page? Are you printing simple plain text or complex images + text?

Comment: @JeremyBoden single labels, they occupy one page at a time. The page size is one label. Most of the time plain text.